# Exception Driven Programming C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf

Although not much popular in Micro-services & Restful architecture, (I'm presuming). We prefer to raise graceful business excetion by means of custom exception classes derived from `ApplicationException`.

> Is there any mechanism to self declare, `by some compile feature` that
>   Ex1, Ex2, Ex3 are the possible business exceptions thrown by a `class service`.
>
> If you're already familiar with WCF, hope you have got it. I'm Something on the lines of WCF
>   (Exception contract)

Example:

```
public class BlobChecksumMatchException : ApplicationException
{
    public BlobChecksumMatchException(string msg) : base(msg)
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT: 
(Not to mention Exception base of course can be thrown for whatsoever reason, I'm just looking out for predefining business exception classes)

Comment: Not sure what you mean but can xml comments help you perhaps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such built-in mechanism in C# or .NET. However, you have a couple of workaround options:

1) If that information is for human consumption, you can use [XML documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/exception) as pointed out by Andreas Zita.

2) If you need a machine-readable mechanism, you could declare a custom "ThrowsException" attribute and apply it to your class or methods, then retrieve these [using reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class MyBusinessClass
{
  [ThrowsException(typeof(Ex1))]
  [ThrowsException(typeof(Ex2))]
  public void DoSomething() {}
}
```

Note however that reflection is expensive, depending on your performance requirements you might need to implement some caching mechanism for that information.